# Get normals from a point to an ellipse

Tags: geometry

I'm working on a small software to get normals from a point to an ellipse.
I have based it on this article: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath505/kmath505.htm and my application works.
However I have a small problem, using a polynomial equation of the fourth degree I get the X coordinates of normals points then I can get Y coordinates with a simple formula (last formula in the article), but the choice of sign, depending on whether it is a convex or concave point of normalcy.
I have understand it but is there a analytic (NOT graphic) method to understand the right sign?

Comment: I'd recommend doing the computation using parametric equations of the ellipse. It still reduces to finding he roots of a fourth degree equation, but there's no sign ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the equation of the ellipse be
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1.
$$
If the point $P$ from which you're trying to find normals is on the $x$ axis then both signs of $y$ are correct. Otherwise, at each of the 
candidate solution points, if the coordinates of the point
are $(x_1,y_1)$, the normal line through that point is
$$
a^2y_1(x−x_1)=b^2x_1(y−y_1).
$$
This gives two lines, one for each choice of sign of $y_1$.
Exactly one of these lines will pass through $P$;
that is the correct normal line.

Comment: I will test it. Can I know how you have found the equation of normal line?

Comment: There's more than one way to do it; one way starts by using implicit differentiation to find the slope. But I was lazy and just looked it up here: http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/math-results-and-formulas/equations-of-tangent-and-normal-to-a-ellipse.html